# How to find rows from a groupby condition in original dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have the following condition which eliminates the last row of a group if that last row does not equal 'no' for the column outcome:

```
m1 = df.groupby(['id'])['outcome'].tail(1) != 'no'
```

I then use this condition to drop these rows from the dataframe:

```
df = df.drop(m1[m1].index)
```

However I do not know how to do the opposite and instead of dropping these rows from the original df, extract entire rows that satisfy the m1 condition. Any suggestions?

Comment: `df = df[m1]` ?

Comment: tried that first but get this error: pandas.core.indexing.IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: `df.loc[m1[m1].index,:]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

```py
df.loc[m1[m1].index, :]
```

will work.